# Grunt LiveReload not showing

Tags: javascript, sass, grunt-contrib-watch, livereload

i have a noob question about livereload with Grunt. I have the watch task configured with livereload: true
I added the  tag at the bottom of the page and when i point the browser to localhost:port_number_i_can't_remember it shows a page with the .js server i guess...

how can i use livereload to reload the html i'm working on. where do i have to point the browser? I'm using sublime3 and added the livereload package. I also use brackets, been on/off between the two.

The grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

sass: {
  options: {
    includePaths: ['sass/**/*.scss']
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      sourceMap: true
    },
    files: {
      'css/materialize.css': 'sass/materialize.scss'
    }
  }
},

watch: {
  grunt: {
    options: {
      livereload: true
    },
    files: [
    'css/*.css',
    '*.html'
    ]
  },

  sass: {
    files: 'sass/**/*.scss',
    tasks: ['sass']
  },

}

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['build', 'watch']);

}
```

What am i doing wrong here guys?

Comment: Could you please post your Gruntfile.js?

Comment: Edited the question with the code form the Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to enable it, and they're listed in the [official wiki](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#enabling-live-reload-in-your-html).

The easiest is the first one, include

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

before `</body>` in your HTML page.

If you have any question on one of these methods, please update the question accordingly

Comment: I already have the sript tag on the html page, just before the ending body tag as i stated in the original question...